# Wordpress wp-admin: add list of pages as submenu items under pages

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin

I would like to customize my wp-admin pages tab like my attachment, I tried with many code but couldn't fix it. I would like to display my crested page list under the "pages" menu in wp-admin.

[image]

I could successfully created a custom menu using this code `add_action('admin_menu' , 'add_custom_meu');`.
I need page under this main menu.

```
function add_custom_meu(){
    add_menu_page('Page Title','My Custom menu' , 'manage_options' , 'my-new-settings' , 'wps_theme_func');
}
add_action('admin_menu' , 'add_custom_meu');
```

Comment: try this `add_submenu_page` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to create a query for all your pages and loop through them and add them as sub-menus using the [`add_submenu_page`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) built in function.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'so_56162955_register_page_submenus');
function so_56162955_register_page_submenus() {
    //get all published pages
    $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'page', 'post_status'=>'publish'));
    if($query->have_posts()) {
        //loop through each page
        while($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            //add each page as a submenu using their own titles
            add_submenu_page(
                'edit.php?post_type=page',
                $query->post->post_title,
                $query->post->post_title,
                'edit_posts',
                '/post.php?post='.$query->post->ID.'&action=edit',
                '' 
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have another question about wordpress url can you help me? i need to Url structure like this in wordpress Sitename.com/ParentPage/ChildPage1/ChildPage2/ChildPage3/ChildPage4 can you help me to find a solution  for this part . thank you